# How to access data from html controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, server-side

How do I access data from html in asp.net in the .cs (code behind) file?

In .aspx page I have:

```
             <tr>
                <td>Username:</td><td><input id="username" type="text" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Password:</td><td><input id="password" type="password" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
```

I know I can convert this to something like:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="username" TextMode="SingleLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Password:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="password" TextMode="Password" runat=server></asp:TextBox></td>
     </tr>
```

This will allow me to access the controls via IDs.
However I was wondering if there was a way of accessing data without using asp.net server-side controls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give the inputs a name as well as an id and you will be able to get the values from [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx).  Inputs without names are not sent back with the form post.

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" />


var username = Request.Form["username"];
var password = Request.Form["password"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `runat="server"` to the controls, and then you can access them from the code-behind almost as if they were `<asp:______ />` controls.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET controls, are in essence HTML controls wrapped, so an `asp:Button` will render as a `input` Html control. 
Some web developers prefer using Html controls due to the smaller size.
Therefore each HTML control will map to a asp server control.
As the previous answer, from Joel, add the `runat="server"`, then the control can be referenced by the ID from the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input id="username" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input id="password" type="password" /></td>
</tr>
```

You can just add the `runat="server"` attribute to the Html controls:

```
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input id="username" runat="server" type="text" />  <!--NOTE THE RUNAT="SERVER"--></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input id="password" **runat="server"** type="password" /></td>
</tr>
```

Now you can access the controls in asp.net.